# log plot problems

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Why does the following code give me two different curves?

```
a = 100;
b = -0.1;
s = a n^b;
LogLogPlot[{s, a n^b}, {n, 1000, 1000000}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: which version of M are you using? I get same plot  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BTwc4.png)

Comment: I get the same curves: [link](https://imgur.com/a/FhKtu) (Mathematica 10.2)

Comment: Add `Remove[a, b, s, n]` at the top

Comment: I added `Remove` with no change. I'm using Mathematica 11.0.0.0.

Comment: I get the same curves (v. 10.4).

Comment: Restart the kernel (`Quit[]`) and try again. If the problem persists, upgrade to 11.0.1 (which is free to you if you have a 11.0.0 license).

Comment: Please clarify "same curves" comments. Do you mean you get the same two curves I'm getting, or are both curves plotting as the same one (which should be the correct behavior)?

Comment: In version 11.0.0 use `Evaluate`, i.e., `LogLogPlot[Evaluate@{s, a n^b}, {n, 1000, 1000000}]`

Comment: I have restarted the kernel, with no change in behavior. Will upgrade, and post the results.

Comment: Ok, so `Evaluate` works. But why wouldn't it work without?

Comment: It "should" work without `Evaluate` (as reflected in later versions); however, when experiencing problems with functions that `Hold` some or all of their arguments it is a good idea to check if `Evaluate` helps.

Comment: I upgraded to version 11.1, and it works as intended now.